# Converting shared_ptr to shared_ptr of same type in different namespace

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I have this `Foo class` where it contains a `shared_ptr` to a `Hotel class`, and a reference to a `Rules class` (which is inside a `namespace` `Rules`):

```
class Foo
{
public:
   //...
   void doStuff();
private:
   std::shared_ptr<Hotel> mHotelClicked;
   Rules::IRules& mRules;
}
```

Where the doStuff() method is implemented in this way:

```
void Foo::doStuff()
{
   //...
   std::shared_ptr<Hotel> p = hotel;

   //Here I need to pass both smart pointers
   if(mRules.isValidMove(mHotelClicked,p) == true) //ERROR here! See bellow.
   {
       //...
   }
}
```

The `Rules` is inside a `namespace` called `Rules` in the following interface:

```
namespace Rules
{
  class IRules
  {
  public:
    virtual bool isValidMove(std::shared_ptr<Hotel> hotel1, std::shared_ptr<Hotel> hotel2) = 0;
    //...
  };
}
```

**ERROR:**

```
error C2664: 'Rules::IRules::isValidMove' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::shared_ptr<_Ty>' to 'std::shared_ptr<_Ty>'
```

When I hover the mouse over the:

```
mRules.isValidMove(mHotelClicked,p)
```

I see the following **ERROR**:

```
No suitable user-defined conversion from "std::shared_ptr<Hotel>" to "std::shared_ptr<Rules::Hotel>" exits.
```

Notice the `Rules::` (maybe because it's from the namespace).

**My two questions:**

- **[1]** How can I fix this error? Since both parameters are the same type? Both are smart pointers to a Hotel class.
- **[2]** What is the best practice to do this? Should I pass by reference instead?

Comment: Do you have two identical classes called Hotel, defined in different namespaces? If so, it's hard to see a justification for that.

Comment: No, the Hotel class is only defined once, and without any namespace. Only the Rules class has its own namespace.

Comment: Ohhh. Sorry then -- I'm afraid this one is over my head.

Comment: The compiler believes that you do have a definition of `Hotel` in namespace `Rules`, as well as one in the global namespace. Realize that `::Hotel` and `Rules::Hotel` are two distinct, completely unrelated classes. Do you, by any chance, `#include "Hotel.h"` from inside `namespace Rules {}`, or something along these lines? If so, cease and desist.

Comment: I agree with Igor. It seems clear that there is something more going on in your code than you have posted here. We'll need to see it before we can help.

Comment: Beside @IgorTandetnik 's suggestion, can you check if you forward declaration of `Hotel` inside namespace `Rules`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What must be happening is that somewhere in the `Rules` namespace there's am erroneous declaration of a `Hotel` class, so

```
virtual bool isValidMove(std::shared_ptr<Hotel> hotel1, std::shared_ptr<Hotel> hotel2) = 0;
```

gets really compiled as

```
virtual bool isValidMove(std::shared_ptr<Rules::Hotel> hotel1, std::shared_ptr<Rules::Hotel> hotel2) = 0;
```

instead of a reference to the `Hotel` class in the global namespace.

When there's an unqualified reference to a class made from within a namespace, the compiler first checks if the class exists inside the namespace, then checks the global namespace (this is somewhat simplified, there are a few other rules, but that's beside the point).

I'm guessing that the declaration of `Rules::Hotel`, somewhere in the header files that you did not show, was in error. You need to find that, and fix it by declaring it outside of the `Rules` namespace.

If you actually do have a different `Rules::Hotel` class (presuming you have a good reason for this), you can change the above declaration to:

```
virtual bool isValidMove(std::shared_ptr<::Hotel> hotel1, std::shared_ptr<::Hotel> hotel2) = 0;
```

in order to force this to reference the `Hotel` class in the global namespace. Ugly, but C++ is not a beauty contest.

Comment: Thank you all! the Hotel class was indeed being forward declaration inside the Rules namespace! :) Thanks!!